# How to write in ARFF file using LIAC-ARFF package in Python?

Tags: python, arff

I want to load an ARFF file in python, then change some values of it and then save changes to file. I'm using `LIAC-ARFF` package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/liac-arff). I loaded ARFF file with following lines of code:

```
import arff
data = arff.load(open(FILE_NAME, 'rb'))
```

After manipulating some values inside `data`, i want to write `data` to another ARFF file. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
import arff
data = arff.load(open(FILE_NAME, 'rb'))
f = open(outputfilename, 'wb')
arff.dump(data, f)
f.close()
```

In the `LICA-ARFF` description you see `dump` method which serializes to a the file, but it's wrong. It just write object as text file. Serialize means save whole the object, so the output file is binary not a text file.

Comment: perfect - I was looking all over for this

Answer (score 0):

We can load arff data into python using scipy.

```
from scipy.io import arff

import pandas as pd

data = arff.loadarff('dataset.arff')

df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

df.head()
```